# Auto click button

Tags: javascript

I have a page, on page I have one button, that button click performs 3 functions. I need to auto call the button click event as soon the single function call done. After completion of each function I added the code

```
script = " document.getElementById('" & btnCreateApprove.ClientID & "').click(); }"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "btnCreateApproveClick", script, True).
```

by adding this code I can call the button click automatically after a function call completion, The page is having one Update panel which says "Processing please wait.." it displays when function is performing its action. After the first auto click I got the error object reference not found for the update panel. I think my auto click call happens before the page fully loaded. Let me know what to do.

Comment: ...are you sure that `document.getElementById('" & btnCreateApprove.ClientID & "')` refers to the correct node? It looks weird to me..

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#printbuttoncustomer').trigger('click'); 
   });
</script> 

<input name="printbuttoncustomer" id="printbuttoncustomer" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're using `&` instead of `+`.
The first line should read:

```
script = " document.getElementById('" + btnCreateApprove.ClientID + "').click(); }"
```

Or else you'll get an error.